# Close a Window programatically after a OK_Button click from a ViewModel using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, window, viewmodel

I am showing a window. The instance is created and shown within the ViewModel (bad practice I know...)

```
NewWindow form = new NewWindow();
form.ShowDialog();
```

Within that form I have an OK_button which is doing stuff when it is pressed. There exist a ViewModel to this form which has the OK Command from the OK_Button.
After that button is pressed doing stuff I want to close that form programatically from within the viewmodel. How can I do that?

I use **WPF**

**UPDATE**

now lets see what I do wrong: Here the DataContext event is not fired although my Window with the ViewModel is shown!?

The window that is shown and must be closed from the ViewModel:

```
public partial class NewSchoolYearWindow : Window
    {
        public NewSchoolYearWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            NewSchoolYearViewModel vm = (NewSchoolYearViewModel)e.NewValue;
            vm.CloseNewSchoolYearDialog += () => this.Close();              
        }
    }
```

Why is the DataContextChanged even not fired?

I use this XAML in my Window:

```
<Window x:Class="TBM.View.NewSchoolYearWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:TBM.ViewModel"
        Title="Start a new school year"
        Height="412" Width="505" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"        
        WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow"
        ResizeMode="CanResize" DataContextChanged="Window_DataContextChanged">
    <Window.Resources>

        <ViewModel:NewSchoolYearViewModel x:Key="NewSchoolYearViewModelID" />

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ., Source={StaticResource NewSchoolYearViewModelID}}" Name="MainGrid">
        <TextBlock Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,46,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="School year start" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" />
        <TextBlock Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,93,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="School year end" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" />
        <TextBlock Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,169,0,0" Name="textBlock4" Text="Database name:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" TextAlignment="Left" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
        <TextBlock Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,215,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="Directory:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" TextAlignment="Left" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding CurrentSchoolYear.Directory}"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,212,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" />
        <Button Command="{Binding OpenNewSchoolYearDialogCommand}" Content="DIR" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,211,27,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54" />
        <Button Command="{Binding CreateNewSchoolYearCommand}" Content="OK" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="381,299,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <Button Content="Cancel" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="300,299,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <DatePicker Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,42,0,0" SelectedDate="{Binding CurrentSchoolYear.Start}" SelectedDateFormat="Long" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" />
        <DatePicker Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,89,0,0" SelectedDate="{Binding CurrentSchoolYear.End}" SelectedDateFormat="Long" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,166,0,0" Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding CurrentSchoolYear.Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: winforms? asp.net? wpf? silverlight?

Comment: winforms and asp.net have no ViewModels AND Commands. So it has to be xaml. So it is WPF :)

Comment: ViewModels and Commands are artifacts of a programming pattern, they are not inherently related to XAML or WPF. That said, of the possibilities given, WPF/Silverlight *is* where they are most likely to be used.

Comment: Its not possible to use MVVM (I stated) in winforms/asp as there exist no databinding two-way. KnockoutJS does not count ;-)

Comment: MVVM is a design pattern - two-way databinding is a tool to make using that pattern easier.  MVVM is platform-agnostic.

Comment: yes perplexed but MVVM can only work with two-way databinding. Without it there is no pattern just half of it :) Back to topic now :p

Comment: Data binding (in both directions) does indeed exist in Windows Forms. It's a feature of the .NET framework, not of a specific presentation technology. [Here's an old, pre-WPF example.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/databindingconcepts.aspx) Further, check out CodePlex for an example of [MVVM in ASP.NET](http://aspnetmvvm.codeplex.com/), and an adaptation of the WPF Application Framework (WAF) to a [WinForms presentation layer.](http://waf.codeplex.com/releases/view/52583) The whole strength of a pattern is its broad applicability. **Now** back to the topic. :)

Comment: Ok that codeproject article is nice and surprised me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an event in the ViewModel:

```
public event EventHandler<CloseRequestedEventArgs> CloseRequested;

protected virtual void OnCloseRequested(bool? dialogResult)
{
    var handler = CloseRequested;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new CloseRequestedEventArgs(dialogResult));
}

...

public class CloseRequestedEventargs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly bool? _dialogResult;

    public CloseRequestedEventargs(bool? dialogResult)
    {
        _dialogResult = dialogResult;
    }

    public bool DialogResult { get { return _dialogResult; } }
}
```

And handle it in the code-behind:

```
var vm = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
vm.CloseRequested += vm_CloseRequested;

...

private void vm_CloseRequested(object sender, CloseRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DialogResult.HasValue)
        this.DialogResult = e.DialogResult; // sets the dialog result AND closes the window
    else
        this.Close();
}
```

Comment: My this.DataContext is NULL because the ViewModel is created after the View instantiation. So that wont work here.

Comment: Not sure I understand what the problem is... just subscribe to the event after the VM is created

Comment: I cant handle this in the codebehind of my window in the Ctor: var vm = (MyViewModel)DataContext; vm.CloseRequested += vm_CloseRequested; because the DataContext is not set yet.

Comment: OK, but can't you do it after the DataContext is set? You could do it in the DataContextChanged event

Comment: seems I run against this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8e4f9b09-fd14-4be7-9d4b-f6038cd61e6d/

Comment: @msfanboy, the DataContext is set on the Grid, not the Window. That's why the event is not fired, because the Windows's DataContext is and remains null. Just set the DataContext on the Window rather than on the Grid, and it should work

Comment: argh... you were right of course the DataContext of the Window never changes as the Binding is set on the UserControl mapped to the ViewModel... thx for showing that.